# C# problem with scrolling to end of UserControl with large amount of content

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I've created UserControl that contains bunch of other controls that are placed also outer area of visible part of my control to cause vertical scrollbar to appear, as expected and required behaviour.

Everything works as it should untill size, amount and location of controls doesn't exceed **some** value. I say **some** cause i couldn't determine which value i exceed and by that I cause my control work not quite well.

Amount of controls inside my UserControl can vary from few to few thousands, depending on circumstances. Controls are same size, displayed in rows/columns. Number of rows, and columns that user see in visible part of UserControl depends on size of controls inside. As far as i know it should be possible for me to operate on values of location as big as max value of **int**. But it seems that im doing something wrong, cause while tests things doesn't work as it should.

While the **Location.Y** value of control at the bottom of my UserControl is for example **49150** scrolling of control doesn't bring me nowhere near that value **VScrollBar.maximum** no matter how much controls i put and how far their **Y location** would be never go bigger than **32896**.

When i change size of my UserControl or size of controls inside, so the **Location.Y** of last control isn't too far, everything works great.

Is there any way that i can fix VScrollBar, or do anything else to get my control work exactly as I need it, or anything else that could cause such problem?

MTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that is the size limit based on when winforms was originally created back when everything was 16 bit.

Comment: 16bits would be 0 - 65535 or −32768 to 32767 when signed and my 32896 exceeds it a bit, any other guess?

Comment: Well in the end it seems that this is in fact the issue i got to deal with, i got to think how to walk around it. The funny part is that there is no error at all. Thank you for pointing that out.